# Мигание и изменение цвета кнопки используя разный интервал времени

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочется сделать кнопку `Сохранить`, чтобы при успешном выполнении операции, которую она вызывает был следующий эффект: она постепенно окрасилась в зеленый цвет, скажем каждые 0.6 секунд она мигает зеленым цветом, 2 раза, потом каждые 0.4 секунды, 2 раза, потом 0.2 секунды 2 раза, т.е. все чаще и чаще, в конце она становится полностью зеленой и не меняется. Где-то 1 секунду, потом обратно окрашивается в свой стандартный цвет. По этому принципу можно сделать и обратный эффект с красным цветом. Если с цветами понятно, то с таймерами беда, прошу помощи.
Программа на C# в VS 2015, WinFormApplication.
Видел такой метод `DispatcherTimer()` но даже поэкспериментировать не получилось, т.к. не могу подключить `using System.Windows.Threading;` ругается

Comment: А почему WinForms? Нетривиальный UI гораздо легче писать на современном WPF. Там ваш вопрос — просто применение анимации.

Comment: Я не совсем понял, добавлю пояснение в вопрос. Смотрите апдейт.

Comment: Я имел в виду WPF, сорри.

Comment: «Ругается» — а как именно?

Comment: Решил проблему, нужно было добавить `WindowsBase.dll` нажав `Add Reference` во вкладке `Project`. Вопроса это не отменяет, вполне возможно, что это мне не поможет :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не специалист в WinForms, но конкретно то, что вы хотите, можно сделать так:

```
async Task PlaySuccessAnimation(Button b, CancellationToken ct)
{
    // проверка
    if (b.UseVisualStyleBackColor == true)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Need overridable color");

    var origColor = b.BackColor;

    var on = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
    try
    {
        // два раза по 0.6 секунд мигаем зелёным
        await Blink(b, Color.Green, on, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), 2, ct);

        // 2 раза по 0.4 секунды
        await Blink(b, Color.Green, on, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3), 2, ct);

        // 2 раза по 0.2 секунды
        await Blink(b, Color.Green, on, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1), 2, ct);

        b.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        b.BackColor = origColor;
        throw;
    }
}

async Task Blink(
    Button b, Color color,
    TimeSpan on, TimeSpan off, int n,
    CancellationToken ct)
{
    var origColor = b.BackColor;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b.BackColor = Color.Green;
        await Task.Delay(on, ct);
        b.BackColor = origColor;
        await Task.Delay(off, ct);
    }
}
```

Я не пробовал, но мне кажется, что выглядеть будет не очень. Пробуйте!

---

Если вы не собираетесь останавливать анимацию, можно использовать просто `CancellationToken.None` в качестве `ct`. Если собираетесь, то пишите так:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
// сохраните cts где-то для дальнейшего использования
await PlaySuccessAnimation(b, cts.Token);
```

а если понадобится оборвать анимацию, то используйте `cts.Cancel()`.

Comment: Ругается на `InvaliOperationException` также как на `DispatcherTimer()`, при попытке подключить `System.InvalidOperationException` тоже ругается, если пробовать добавить dll - `mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)` This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

Comment: @Agasi: Если вы будете писать «ругается», никто вас не поймёт. Не компилируется? Тогда какая ошибка и в какой строке? Выбрасывается исключение? Тогда какое, какой текст, какой stack trace, в какой строке, чему равны значения переменных, упомянутых в этой строке? И т. д.

Comment: @Agasi: А, понял, у меня опечатка. Нужно `InvalidOperationException`. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Ага, и я нашел) еще `Color.` вместо `Colors.`, это я отправил на правку. Глупый вопрос, я не знаком с этими конструкциями, как правильно вызвать ваш метод, через Event `button1_Click`?

Comment: О, вы не знакомы с async/await? Можно, например, обработку click, да. Только не забудьте `await`: `await PlaySuccessAnimation(...)`. И метод, который это вызывает, объявите `async`. В любом случае, срочно читать про async/await, это же одна из главных фишек C#!

Comment: Да, не знаком, недавно начал изучать C#, обязательно почитаю. Вроде все сделал, не пойму, что нужно передать в качестве параметра для `CancellationToken ct`? Код:  `await PlaySuccessAnimation(sender, ?);` а `sender` это я передаю кнопку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32324/discussion-between-agasi-mkhitaryan-and-vladd).